# Make CSS and HTML menu with a bottom border longer than the longest word in the menu

Tags: html, css, menu, border

I need a CSS and HTML menu with `<li>` items that each have a bottom border that is longer than the longest word in the menu.

example:

```
Menu 1    Secondly      Againnextmenu
-------   ----------    ----------------
```

I editing on opencart. css:

```
#menu {

    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 37px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    z-index: 20;
    padding: 6px 5px 5px 0px;

}
#menu > ul > li:hover {

}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
}
#menu > ul > li:hover > a {
    background: #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu > ul > li > div {
    display: none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    background: url('../image/menu.png');
}
#menu > ul > li:hover > div {
    display: table;
}
#menu > ul > li > div > ul {
    display: table-cell;
}
#menu > ul > li ul + ul {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu > ul > li ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 120px;
}
#menu > ul > li ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #000000;
}
#menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And here is code html:

```
      <?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the bottom border need to be longer than the word within the `<li></li>` tag?

Comment: Andre, yes. Added code.

Comment: Is the example a drop down menu and you need the border on the parent to be long enough to accommodate  all the menu contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give padding right to li's

```
li{
border-bottom:1px dashed #000;
padding-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: @user3791464  also to add try to use display inline-block instead of float.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
 #menu > ul > li {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        z-index: 20;
        padding: 6px 5px 5px 0px;
        border-bottom:1px dashed #000;

    }
```